# Using ggplot to create a choropleth from a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, ggplot2, census

I have a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame that comes from the UScensus2010 package.  I am trying to create a choropleth.  When I do so, this works as expected:

```
data(colorado.county10)
choropleth(colorado.county10,
           "P0010001",
           color = list(fun = "rainbow", 
                        attr = list(4)),
           main="2010 US Counties",
           type="plot",
           border="black")
```

but this fails due to 'P0010001' not being found

```
data(colorado.county10)
ggplot(colorado.county10, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = P0010001), colour = alpha("white", 1/2), size = 0.2) +
  scale_fill_brewer(pal = "PuRd")
```

As I've tried to figure this out, I've noted that colorado.county10$P0010001 returns an array of numbers, but colorado.county10[,"P0010001"] returns a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

Any insights into what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `ggplot` you need to coerce from a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` to a `data.frame`.

`ggplot2` provides a number of `fortify` methods that will create the correctly formatted data.

Currently the `fortify.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` method does not retain the `data` component, it does provide a column `id` which contains the rownames from the `data.frame` within the `data` slot of the original `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`.

Note that `data.frames` are an inefficient way to store this information (1 row for each vertex for each polygon).

Thus the following will work, but is slow and may cause memory issues

```
c10 <- fortify(colorado.county10)

c10d <- cbind(c10, colorado.county10@data[c10$id,])

ggplot(c10d, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
   geom_polygon(aes(fill = factor(P0010001)), colour = alpha("white", 1/2), size = 0.2) +
   scale_fill_brewer(pal = "PuRd")
```

Using `base` plotting functions will be much faster and not chew up as many resources.