# making a choropleth from SpatialPolygonsDataFrame- ggplot vs ggplot2 vs plot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a shapefile, specifically, a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, called cdtract. that contains one variable for each district called varcount. varcount is either "NA" or 1. When I do

```
plot(cdtract)
```

...I see the map printed out but I don't see the tracts that are '1' in varcount marked any differently from those that are 'NA.' I ideally want to have a spectrum of values in varcount and see those reflected in different colors. I considered using ggplot but according to [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039297/using-ggplot-to-create-a-choropleth-from-a-spatialpolygonsdataframe) that is very resource intensive and it might be better to use plot() instead of ggplot() to create the choropleth. But I'm really not sure how to go about it. I am using a different shapefile from states/countries so am not sure that the choroplethr package is the way to go.

Can someone explain how to take a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and turn it into a choropleth, efficiently? Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered `spplot` from `lattice`?

Comment: I have not, I am looking into that right now.

Comment: Can you provide any guidance about how to use spplot to create this kind of choropleth for the variable varcount, @RomanLuštrik? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shamefully taken from [Ari's post on gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36877/how-do-i-change-the-polygon-fill-color-and-border-color-for-spatialpolygons-obje). See the link for pictures. There are more examples [here](http://rspatial.r-forge.r-project.org/gallery/).

```
library(sp)

Srs1 = Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))), "s1")
Srs2 = Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(5,4,2,5),c(2,3,2,2)))), "s2")

SpDF <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame( SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1,Srs2)), 
                                  data.frame(z=1:2, row.names=c("s1","s2") ) )
spplot(SpDF, zcol="z")
```

Comment: thanks! that did it. also i had no idea about gis.stackexchange.com. awesome!